# How to merge entities in an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD)

Tags: erd

I am working on a ERD for a college. A student can rent a flat or a residence. Both entities have similar attributes and I was told to combine them into one, and add attributes that would let me differentiate whether a student was in a flat or residence.

What I'm thinking to do is to create two attributes with different names. For example each flat and residence has a manager, so I will create an attribute call `FlatManager` and another one called `ResidenceManager`.

When I insert student information that is renting a flat I will insert information for only columns that have "Flat" at the beginning and leave the residence ones null.

Answer (score 0):

You will lose the benefits of merging to one entity if you rename the attributes differently depending on whether it is a residence or a flat.

How about you just add a boolean attribute that serves as a flag to distinguish between flats and residences.  (e.g. isResidence)